# How to use a record variable in the from clausule

Tags: postgresql

I write a SQL function that receives and return a record. I need to use the received record in a from clause. I am using `unnest(array[the_variable])`.

Is there a specific function or structure to do this? (something like `record_to_recordset(the_variable)`)

Here is my example:

```
create type calculate_info_type as (super_code text, super_name text);

create function calculate_info(p_country country) 
   returns calculate_info_type 
   language SQL as
$SQL$
   SELECT super_code, super_name 
     FROM unnest(array[p_country]), -- <=== HERE!!
          lateral (select 
            prefix is not null as has_prefix
          ) g1,valores que tenga la tabla
          lateral (select 
            case has_prefix when true then iso||'-'||prefix else iso end as super_code,
            case has_prefix when true then name else name||' without phone prefix' end as super_name
          ) g2 
$SQL$;
```

I put a complete running example here: https://rextester.com/XIRSW33377

Comment: So you want the columns of that record variable as rows? I am not sure I understand what you are after, could you please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data?

Comment: No I do not. I want the same behavior of `unnest (array [row_var])`. I need to transform a record into a recordset with one record. I need to put row_var in the from clausule

Comment: Not in this case because I put  my var inside an `array [ x ]` construct. Unnest returns a recordset with  one row (as I expect) because the array has one element (of type record). But I feel someway unhappy to do it in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer** *(edited)*

You can write `FROM (select p_country.*) some_alias` instead of `FROM unnest(array[p_country])`

Question code with minimal corrections: https://rextester.com/UGKJR74935

**Original answer** *(with many usefull suggestions)*

Looks like you want something like this:

```
create function calculate_info(p_country country) 
   returns calculate_info_type 
   language SQL as
$SQL$
   select case when has_prefix then iso||'-'||prefix else iso end as super_code,
          case when has_prefix then name else name||' without phone prefix' end as super_name
   FROM (
      select (p_country).*, p_country.prefix is not null as has_prefix
   ) as c
$SQL$;
```

But you don't really need the `from` at all:

```
create function calculate_info(p_country country) 
   returns calculate_info_type 
   language SQL 
as
$SQL$
   select concat_ws(',', p_country.iso, p_country.prefix) super_code,
          case 
            when p_country.prefix is not null then p_country.name 
            else p_country.name||' without phone prefix' 
          end as super_name;
$SQL$;
```

`concat_ws` will return only the value from the `iso` field if `prefix` is null.

You don't need a `lateral` to use that function:

```
select iso, prefix, name, (calculate_info(country)).*
from country
```

Your updated example: https://rextester.com/GVLK52206

Comment: Are there known problems for using lateral? I use lateral because I write many variables based in previous calculated variables (my example was simplificated). When I write in the traditional way I need to nest many level of selects. With lateral I can write the same thing without nesting a select for each group of variables.